# How to identify pixels with noise

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I was wondering if EmguCV provides any function for detecting (just detecting, not correcting) the number of pixels with noise within an image

Take this picture for example : http://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/ResearchMaterial/SIMPAR-Denoising/zelda512-NoiseV400.gif  , whose size is 512x512 (or 262,144 pixels).

Would it be possible to get the total number of noisy pixels ? i.e 150,321 noisy pixels out of 262,144 total pixels.

What approach do you suggest ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A first approach is just to count the black and white pixels. But this will also count the saturated back and white areas. So a better way is to count the isolated (no equal neighbor) black and white pixels.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need that ? In my whole career I have never seen such salt&pepper images elsewhere than in textbooks.

Comment: Actually is not just salt and pepper noise, but  also electronic noise , and others in general . My idea is to run an image correction algorithm  , only if it exceeds a certain threshold. As running an image correction indiscriminately, might result in unnecessary  image quality degrading.